# PDF File hides under a toolbar on display

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

Good day,

I'm working on an iOS app to display and sign pdf files using pdfTron. When my fil[e is displayed on the viewController, it used to cut at the top - I then unchecked "Under top bars" on my storyboard and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBXjB.jpg) became fine. Now is leaving a bigger space on the top just below the navigationController and is cutting at the bottom. See images attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBXjB.jpg)

Comment: It is incredibly difficult to tell what is supposed to be conveyed in that screen shot. Could you be more descriptive or possibly highlight the areas of the UI that are being problematic?

Comment: how are to displaying pdf on view controller ?. Is it a new view controller pushed ? or a view being added? In case of view how are you setting its position ?

Comment: @aman.sood I'm displaying the pdf via [self.navigationController pushViewController:view anomated:Yes]; when I'm importing a new pdf file from other apps, it displays ok, but if I display a file from my uitableview list as a push, it appears like that.

Comment: So if i am right that means your tableView controller is set as root of navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

put this in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: This hides the navigationController which I have buttons for certain features on it and cant go back.

Answer (score 0):

Try out setting "top bar" as translucent.

If this doesn't work please let me know your view controller flow with code then only i can help you out.